# Update two non-associated models with one submit button, using nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a `User` controller that possesses the two following records:

`user.vehicles` from `VehiclesController`
`user.trip_distances` from `TripDistancesController`

In the `Vehicles` view, I need to display and update both models (`Vehicle` and `TripDistance`)

I figured out that I need to use a `nested form`. However, I don't understand how to implement it since my `@trip_distances` record needs a loop in order to display all of its content.

First, I tried to put this in the `Vehicle` model, but since both are NOT linked, I wonder if this is correct:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :trip_distances, allow_destroy: true
```

Then, in the `Vehicle` view's `_form` file, during the `edit` action, I have:

```
<%= form_for(@vehicle) do |f| %>
```

I need to put my nested form inside it. Here's what I got so far:

```
<% @trip_distances.each do |t| %>
  <%= f.fields_for t do |fields| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= fields.text_field :id_contract %>
      <%= fields.number_field :length %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end -%>
```

My `trip_distances` records are correctly displayed, but the unique Submit button doesn't work anymore. I'd like to update both model while clicking on one button. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you have UserController, TripDistancesController and VehicleController? Or you wanted to say you have User, TripDistances and Vehicle models (not controllers)?

Comment: I have both, Controllers and Models.

Comment: Ok, assuming you have User model containing Vehicles and TripDistances I would use user model to show Vehicles details and TripDistances (pass @user to the view).

Comment: If I correctly understood, I would use @user inside the Vehicle _form, right?

Comment: I don't see how I could use @ user since in the Vehicle controller I need to parse the records (which vehicles and trip distances, authorization) and store them in variables (@vehicles and @trip_distances.

Comment: It seems that I understand now what you want to achieve. Try  <% t.fields_for :trip_distances do |fields| %>  instead of <% @trip_distances.each do |t| %><%= f.fields_for t do |fields| %>.

Comment: It doesn't work either. I think it is because Vehicles and TripDistances are not associated. Is it a mandatory prerequisite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by associating the two models. Then I use the following fields_for tag:

```
<%= f.fields_for :trip_distances do |builder| %>
```

My submit button is now working, but the :trip_distances fields are not updated, I don't know why.